# How to change targeted mob in Dungeon Siege 3?

Tags: pc, dungeon-siege-3

I recently installed Dungeon Siege 3 and I was very excited about the Game. I think it´s great but there is one thing, that really bugs me out.

How can I change the selected mob? I mean, if a mob is targeted, how can I change the target to another mob that maybe needs to get stunned or something.

I tried the tabulator button like in some other RPGs, but that only toggles the minimap.

Is there any way to do this?

Am I missing on something here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On PC I usually engage in a dodge movement to change my position and stop firing. It seems you can't change target without breaking the firing cycle.

I've found it very difficult to change target while clicking repeatedely on fire button. 
By the way, they said they will improve controls on PC, I hope this kind of things will be put into the loop.

Comment: FWIW, what you're describing is how it is on the PS3: everything is auto-target based on what direction you're facing, how far away the mob is, and line-of-sight.

Comment: Well, they did not make any effort on the PC version, I've one day fired at the opposite of where my mouse was pointing so...

Comment: I guess I will have to live with it ;-) I experienced the same thing like M'vy did. "Running away" seems to work for the moment